# Meaning of axe in "Axe me a question!"

Tags: pronunciation

What is the meaning of axe in: "Axe me a question!"

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

It's dialect for 'Ask". The /k/ and /s/ sounds have been transposed.

Comment: In a process known as *metathesis*.

Answer (score 1):

I edited my answer with proper etymology.

Simple answer is that it is dialect for 'ask'

This is the origin of the word:

Old English
Alternative forms

> ācsian, āxian
>      āhsian

Etymology

West Proto-Germanic *aiskōną, from Proto-Indo-European *ais-. Cognate with Old Frisian āskia, Old Saxon ēscon, Old High German eiscōn. The Indo-European root is also the source of Latin aeruscare, Old Armenian այց (aycʿ), Slavic *jīskātī (Old Church Slavonic искати, Russian искать), Baltic *eiška- (Lithuanian ieškoti).
Pronunciation

> > IPA(key): /ˈɑːskiɑn/

Verb

āscian

> to demand, seek from
>   to ask, to enquire
>
> > Hwæt me ahsast be þam? Why did you ask me about that? (Ælfric's Colloquy)
>
> to call for, summon; to inquire into
>
> > Ne ascige ic nu owiht bi ðam bitran deaþe minum. I demand nothing now for my bitter death. (Codex Exoniensis)

However, in America it is often thought of as an African-American Vernacular English (AAVE) or the less liked term Ebonics usage. Often this usage and dialect is criticized as a lack of education.

If you want to look at it from proper modern English usage, it is wrong. It should be 'ask', not 'axe'.

However, the AAEV permits this usage as well as other dialects in the US, UK and abroad.

Basically, it is a matter of pronunciation and not the use of the actual word axe (as in a tool used to chop wood.) It is a phonetical replacement for the word ask.

Comment: You're right. Many dialects have adopted this usage. However, I am almost positive it started from AAEV and spread from there.

Comment: Just found an article about this in particular. AAEV seems to take the most credit in recent times for this usage but I found that even the Bible has been translated with 'axe' instead of 'ask' http://www.npr.org/blogs/codeswitch/2013/12/03/248515217/why-chaucer-said-ax-instead-of-ask-and-why-some-still-do "Axe and it shall be given."

Comment: Indeed. OE ascian vs acsian.